# Prototyping a sub-classes to already defined classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, subclass

Sorry if it is trivial but I am a very beginner. In Javascript what is the best way to extend an already defined object class with propreties which are classes themselves?
For example suppose I have a class `Sprite` with some built in properties and methods. I want to have an extra property `Sprite.position` where the `position` part is a class with (say) two properties `position.x` and `position.y`. And I want it applied all the instances of the class `Sprite` (past and future), not to one single instance.
If `position` would be a simple input data (number or string) then I could just write `Sprite.prototype.position='there'`. Also if `position` was an array it would have been easy: just write `Sprite.prototype.position="there"`, or even an array of array would work like this... But what if `position` is a class? Usually to build "classes" one would use the object constructor:

```
function position(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
 }
```

but then I would need to instantiate the `position` objects with `var myPosition = new position(0,0);`  but I want the position object to exist every time I instantiate a new `Sprite` object. If I write `Sprite.prototype.position=new position(0,0);`than there is a problem: if I define `mySprite1.position.x=2` the value `2` is also given to the property `position.x` of every istance of the class Sprite. This doesn't happen with the command `Sprite.prototype.position='there'`, in this case every istance will have and keep his own separate values. I want every istance with separate independent "position" objects.

Is it possible to do what I want in an easy linear way?

Comment: What's wrong with creating a new instance of `Position` in the `Sprite` constructor? Seems like a good approach.

Comment: *"Also if position was an array it would have been easy: just write `Sprite.prototype.position=[0,0]`"* That's exactly the same as doing `Sprite.prototype.position=new SomeClass();` In both cases, **all** `Sprite` objects will refer to the **same** array or object. So in your example `sprite1.position[0] = 2;` means that `sprite47.position[0]` is now `2`, because `sprite1.postion === sprite47.position`.

Comment: *"...because `sprite1.postion === sprite47.position`..."* Well, it would if I hadn't missed out the first `i` in `postion`. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The problem with `Sprite.prototype.position=new position(0,0);` is that if I define `mySprite1.position.x=2` then the value `2` is also given to the property `position.x` of every istance of the class Sprite. This doesn't happen with the command `Sprite.prototype.position=[0,0]`, in this case every istance will have and keep his own separate values.

Comment: @Marco: No, that's incorrect. The two are exactly the same, as I said (and demonstrated) in my answer below. The array has the same problem the object has (because arrays are objects).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually I tried them together to check if the behavior is the same and I find they behave differently, check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pokipsy/wvNTc/2/

Comment: @Marco: Did you bother to read my answer? Again, I explain and demonstrate this there. In your fiddle, your tests are not equivalent. You're just modifying the object, but you're *replacing* the array. Here are the equivalent tests: http://jsfiddle.net/wvNTc/3/ (modifying the object and array) and http://jsfiddle.net/wvNTc/5/ (replacing the object and array). **Again**: Arrays and objects are treated exactly the same, because arrays *are* objects.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please be kind. Actually I see a difference because with arrays and single valued variables I am still able to give separate values to every instance in the way I do in my fiddle (although not in the natural way as one would like to) while with the object apparently I am not able to do so in any way.

Comment: @Marco: (Sorry.) Arrays aren't single valued variables. [Arrays are objects](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). Just as your `position` objects have properties called `x` and `y`, `Array` objects have properties called `0` and `1` and such. This isn't an abstraction, it's *literally* how they're defined in JavaScript. Arrays are just objects based on `Array.prototype` that have a literal notation and a magic `length` property. There is nothing else special about them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, I now checked what happen if I write `Sprite1.prototype.position={x:0,y:0}` (in analogy to `Sprite1.prototype.position=[0,0]`) and I found out that it changes only the properies in `Sprite1` and not other instances-> http://jsfiddle.net/Pokipsy/bL5CC/

Comment: @Marco: You're making the same mistake there that you did with arrays. You're **replacing** the object, not updating its properties. There's no fundamental difference between `...prototype.position={x:0,y:0}` and `...prototype.position = new position();` (other than the prototype assigned to the object).

Comment: @elclanrs You are right but if the class is in a library it would be nice to extend it without editing the library itself.

Answer (score 1):

> And I want it applied all the instances of the class `Sprite` (past and future), not to one single instance.

You're quite right that if you were dealing with a primitive (like your `"testing"` string), you could just add it to `Sprite.prototype` and it would appear on all `Sprite` objects without any crosstalk between them.

> Also if position was an array it would have been easy: just write `Sprite.prototype.position=[0,0]`

While it's true that the array would show up on all `Sprite` objects, they would have the potential for cross-talk, because they'd all share the **same** array:

```
var sprite1 = new Sprite();
var sprite2 = new Sprite();
Sprite.prototype.position = [0,0];
sprite1.position[0] = 42;
console.log(sprite2.position[0]); // "42"
```

If you don't mind them all sharing the same array/object, you can do exactly the same thing with your class:

```
Sprite.prototype.position = new Position(/*...*/);
```

Again, they will all share **one** `Position` object.

If you want each sprite instance to have its **own** `Position` object (or array), independent of the one on other instances, you have only two choices:

1. Modify the `Sprite` constructor to assign the object/array to the instances as they're created.
2. Spin through all `Sprite` objects ever created and add the object/array.

Obviously you can't do #2 unless you have references to those objects.

---

It may well be that you don't have to do anything to `Sprite.prototype` at all, depending on how you want to handle a sprite not having a `position`. For example:

```
function doSomethingWithASprite(sprite) {
    if (!sprite.position) {
        // Doesn't have a position yet, give it one
        sprite.position = new Position(/*...relevant args...*/);
    }
}
```

Similarly, any time you want to *get* a sprite's position:

```
var x = sprite.position && sprite.position.x;
```

That will give you `undefined` if the sprite doesn't have a position yet.

---

A final option for you: Make `position` a function:

```
Sprite.prototype.position = function(x, y) {
    // Make sure we have a position
    if (!this.position) {
        this.position = new Position(/*...relevant args...*/);
    }

    if (typeof x === "undefined") {
        // Getter, return the current position
        return this.position;
    }
    else {
        // Setter, set the current position
        this.position.x = x;
        this.position.y = y;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit descouraging in particular when the classes belong to big libraries. Are there other strategies to mimic the same result without extending the classes? Maybe attaching "pointers" instead of objects?

Comment: @Marco: Well, when you attach an object, you *are* attaching a pointer (reference). I'm afraid I'm not coming up with alternatives other than the two above, sadly.

Comment: I was thinking something like defining `Spite.prototype.position="positionName"`, and then filling it (for any instance) with a string like "myPosition1" which is the name of a specific instance of the class `position`.

Comment: @Marco: What is it you actually want to do with these positions? I'm thinking you probably don't have to do anything to the `Sprite.prototype` at all.

Comment: @Marco: I have to disappear, but I've added a couple of further ideas to the answer.

Comment: I am using Kineticjs library and Kinetic.Image class which has actual positions coordinates x,y. But I have to store also information about a "base position". I could use `Kinetic.Image.prototype.basePositionX=0` and `Kinetic.Image.prototype.basePositionY=0`. But in fact I have several base positions for any Image so I would need to attach an array or an object...